# Creating a has_one through a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I currently have a `ProductSale` model that has_many sales.
Also a sale belongs to an invoice.

My goal is to access an invoice through a `ProductSale`'s association to sales. (product_sale.invoice)

Current `ProductSale` model below:

```html
class ProductSale < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sales
    has_one :invoice, through: :sales
end
```

However my current error is saying that this can't be done because the `:through association is a collection`, which i understand. Is there a way that this can be possible?

```html
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice
 end
```

```html
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sales, inverse_of: :invoice, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: How can Rails know which sale to take in order to get the invoice? it can't. this needs to be a model method where you put the right logic.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. In my case, every sale will have the same invoice_id, so i thought rails might be able to work it out from there. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the sales on the `ProductSale` object have the same invoice.  You know that you can just use the invoice of the first sale, but associations won't know that all the sales have the same invoice so you can use any, for instance the first one.

To have a `invoices` method to get each of the invoices you could do this:

```
class ProductSale < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sales
    has_many :invoices, through: :sales
end
```

However, if you want to use your business logic that all the invoices are assumed to be the same, you will have to write a method to implement that business logic.

```
class ProductSale < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sales

    def invoice
      sales.first&.invoice
    end
end
```

If all the sales on the invoice will be sales in the `ProductSale` object, then maybe you should refactor as below.

```
class ProductSale < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :invoice
    delegate :sales, :to => :invoice, :prefix => false, :allow_nil => true
end
```

Then you can both call the `invoice` method to get the invoice and also call the `sales` method to get all the sales on the invoice for the `ProductSale` object.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```rb
class ProductSale < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sales
  has_one :sale
  has_one :invoice, through: :sale
end
```